Cant access deployed HTML/js files in Azure Web App
im very new to Azure so apologise if this is a stupid question.
Can I manually deploy a html and vanilla js project to Azure Web App? (Not Azure Static Web App)?
I have built my files and deployed to a Web App (App Service) that I created via VS Code Azure App Service plugin. On inspection of the directory via the SSH option in my Web App, I can see that all my files have been deployed to /home/site/wwwroot/ which is what I would expect. However when accessing my app URL I get presented with the default "Your web app is running and waiting for your content" page... I also cant access my html files via /index.html as I get "Cannot GET /index.html".
My web app is set up for code deployment with a Node.js runtime, can I not deploy static html files to this app?
Mor info:
I am deploying the following folder:
Folder build:

app

css
fonts
images
js


libraries
index.html
icon-page.html
... other html pages

The build folder contains an "app" folder which has all of the built js and css code. The build folder also has multiple .html files...
I am building the app before deploying it via the VS Code Azure App service extension...
My Azure App service (Web App) Publishing model is set to "Code". When I deploy the build folder to the Web App via VS code I can see that the  files have been deployed correctly as they are present in "/home/site/wwwroot" when I SSH into the Web App. However, when I access the web app url the index.html page is not shown

How you are deploying your app?

Can you please share your folder structure. If possible please share your code repo.

@Harshitha I have added "more info" above. Im deploying via VS Code Azure App service extension and my files are successfully being added to /home/site/wwwroot. However, they are not being shown when accessing web app url.

Are you deploying to Azure Linux or Windows environment?

What is your Node JS Version?

@Harshitha Node - 20-lts and Linux

Are you following any doc ?

No, I couldn't find a doc for a simple code/html deployment. I have been following chatGPT instructions

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Deploying Node JS App to Azure App Service from VSCode/Visual Studio needs npm packages to be installed.

You need package.json,server.js files to run a Node JS App.

I have also tried to deploy using Azure CLI.

Create an Azure App Service with Runtime Stack Node.


Create static files which you want(html/css).

Locally, open Azure CLI. Navigate to the WebApp Root directory and run az login.




I have referred this MSDoc to run Azure CLI Commands.

Linux:
az webapp up --resource-group MyRG --name StaticAppMay --plan AppservicePlanName --runtime "node|20-lts" 


App is deployed successfully but even I am getting the default content page with Linux.

Only App Service with windows is working here.


Windows:
>az webapp up --resource-group v-harshithav-Mindtree --name StaticAppMay --plan plan-cinsider-test-eastus --html


Output:

One option to server static files is to use Storage Account Static website.

Upload static files to Storage Account => Containers => $web.



Enable Static Website and access the Endpoint.



But as per your requirement(to generate OAuth)  token in Azure App Service Authentication, recommended to follow this MSDoc to create Node JS Linux App Service.

